# Unhandled exception at 0x00831D39 in Myfile.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00E42000)

Tags: c++

I'm stressed out because of the error (I think only in my computer)

I was able to compile it on this wepsite (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) but only fail in my computer.

Anyone who knows why...?

plz help me out

you can only check  (int sum[505][505];      //// This part is causing that error) this line

The error is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM1TY.png)

```
        int N;
        cin >> N;
        int input[500][500];
        int sum[505][505];      //// This part is causing that error
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where is the error ?

Comment: Do you have room for 2 MB on the stack ?

Comment: I entered the image again

Comment: @SidS I don't know how to check but... I think I have since this problem wasn't solved even after reboot

Comment: @AntonioSEO -- *since this problem wasn't solved even after reboot* -- This has nothing to do with some sort of "computer failure" where you need a reboot.  The issue is just poor programming, i.e. blowing out the stack using gigantic local arrays being declared.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 
Well Thx, I thought so since it was implemented on another compiler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating `(500*500 + 505*505) * sizeof(int) = 2020100` bytes on the stack.  Your stack isn't that big, so it overflows.

You'd be better off using dynamic memory, e.g. by means of a `vector<>` :

```
vector<vector<int>> input(500, vector<int>(500));
```

Comment: Thx Sid S
Hw can I check my stack's capacity??
Actually I bought my laptop recently

Comment: You shouldn't.  Use dynamic memory.

Comment: U mean I can't check it?

Comment: It depends on your linker options.